# How to write this in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get details of a PROJECT from Table_1, the primary key is PROJECT_ID.

But this Table_1 holds several rows of details of "report_code" against the same project_id.

I need to extract only those projects that don't have the report_code "COSTS".

A single project could have rows of COSTS codes and TIME codes against it.

Comment: Pro tip consider writing your question & giving it a title that can be searched and explains what you're trying to do. Right now its written in a way that's only going to help you. A clear description, a diagram of the table schema's, a sample of what you've tried, any research you've covered, etc all help make a good question.

Comment: `select <details> from table_1 where /*those projects*/ project_id /*that don't have*/ not in (select /*projects*/ filt.project_id from table_1 filt where /*that have report_code=COSTS*/ where filt.report_code='COSTS')` The easiest way to write a SQL code is, not surprisingly, to start writing.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the projects that don't have the report code "COSTS", you can use the following
SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT_ID
FROM Table_1
WHERE PROJECT_ID NOT IN (
  SELECT PROJECT_ID
  FROM Table_1
  WHERE report_code = 'COSTS'
);
```

1. The outer query selects the distinct project IDs from Table_1.
2. The WHERE clause filters out project IDs that have report_code = 'COSTS'. This is done using a subquery that selects project IDs with report_code = 'COSTS', and the NOT IN operator excludes those project IDs from the outer query's result.

This query will return a list of project IDs that don't have the report code "COSTS". If you need additional details about these projects, you can join the result of this query with the original table using the project ID as the join key.

Answer (score 0):

> The primary key is `PROJECT_ID`.
>
> But this `Table_1` holds several rows of details of `report_code` against the same `project_id`.

This does not make sense as a primary key is unique and can only occur once. If we assume that it is not a primary key and, as per the rest of your description, does occur multiple times then you can use conditional aggregation with the `COUNT` analytic function (to do it with a single table scan):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE report_code WHEN 'COSTS' THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY project_id) AS num_costs_reports
  FROM   table_1 t
)
WHERE  num_costs_reports = 0
```

If `project_id` is a primary key then each `project_id` can only occur once and you simply need:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_1 
WHERE  report_code IS NULL
OR     report_code != 'COSTS'
```